# Meteor call to api resulted in double entries

Tags: meteor

I am using Loopback for my backend api server to my database and Meteor for the frontend. In Meteor, I am using Axios to call the api.

I wanted to use Meteor.call so that I can manage all the related api calls functions within the same file for easier management, e.g. invoice get, add, edit, delete all within invoice file, etc.

If I were to call the Axios to post to the API directly on form submit, the record in my database shows only one record inserted (which is what is expected). But if I were to call the Axios from within a Meteor.call it will result in the database having double entries of the same context.

I don't quite understand why or where the double entry comes from. Could anyone kindly explain?

Thanks.

My Meteor method call to api to insert a new textContext:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    'textContext.insert': function(myText, token) {
        new SimpleSchema({
            myText: {
                type: String,
                min: 1
            },
            token: {
                type: String,
                label: 'Authorization',
                min: 1
            }
        }).validate({myText, token});

        const jsonToken = JSON.parse(token);
        const url = `http://localhost:3001/v1/users/${jsonToken.userId}/textContexts`;
        const data = {
            text_context: myText,
            user_id: jsonToken.userId
        };

        return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url,
            headers: {'Authorization': jsonToken.token},
            data
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err instanceof Error) {
                console.log('Error:', err.message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

TextContext Model in Loopback, text-context.json, extended from textContextBasic which only contains a created_at:

```js
{
  "name": "textContext",
  "base": "textContextBasic",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "text_context": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "user_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "createOrReplace"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "findById"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "findOne"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "find"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

User.json model in the Loopback:

```js
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "created_at": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "default": "$now"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "default": "$now"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "textContexts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "textContext",
      "foreignKey": "user_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__get__textContext"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__create__textContext"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__findById__textContext"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__updateById__textContext"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: And where is the API code?

Comment: I didn't write any API code as it is generated from Loopback, I only set the model, added the textContext model. When I tested it with express.js, the api is working correctly, so did it worked correctly when I tested with the explorer that comes along with Loopback.

Comment: When I did the post request with axios from Meteor directly during the form submit, the textContext insert is correctly done with 1 record, but not when it is done through the Meteor call to the same post request, it generates 2 records. I don't think it is an issue with the API.

Comment: Where are you calling the method from? A helper or an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the source of the problem, it will need to be enclosed in `(Meteor.isServer)` since it is in client.